# The install of solidity extension was failed for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, solidity

I tried to install solidity extension for Visual Studio 2017, I downloaded VSIX Installer from the link bellow:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity
when I tried to run the VSIX file, the installation failed immediately with the given message:
"**Install Failed**
The install of the extension was not successful for all the selected products. For more information, click the install log link at the bottom of the dialog.
This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."

I also tried to read the log file but it is very huge and many different things happened there. I appreciate if someone who had the same experience and fixed it could advice me how to fix it.

Comment: which visual studio 2017 edition (Enterprise, pro, community) do you use? also which version do you use (15.3 or 15.4 preview)?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is trying to install on VS 2017 just open the extract the package and then edit the extension.vsixmanifest to change the wrongly added brackets to square brackets. As below:

```
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" /> 
<InstallationTarget Version="[14.0,15.0]" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed. Installed successfully with warning. Still need to test in visual studio. For newbies - 1. Change extension of vsix to zip ...2. Extract folder...3. Make changes as suggested by Mohamed...4. Zip folder again...5. Change extension to vsix..6. Run installer

Answer (score 1):

If still you face issue, With out converting to .zip file, do " Open Archive " - With in that edit the files as below

```
<Installation>
.... Version="[14.0,15.0]"
.... Version="[14.0,15.0]"
.... Version="[14.0,15.0]"
</Installation>

<Dependencies>
.... Version="[4.5,]"
</Dependencies>
```

save the file and run as it. ( Here there is no conversion from vsix to zip and back - edit is direct on the vsix ) - Installation is success for me.

Comment: I have the same issue as this. Can you tell me in which file should I do these changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The page says "Works with Visual Studio 2015".