# Installation of solidity in windows 10 using visual studio 2017

Tags: solidity

Tried installing solidity using visual studio 2017 but it's not working. My question is that will vs 17 supports solidity or not?

If possible please try to share the step by step process to install solidity for windows10

```
Script: C:\Windows\system32\truffle.js
Line: 1,
Char 1,
Error: 'module' is undefined
Code: 800A1391
Source : Microsft JScript runtime error.
```

[image]

Comment: Hello - welcome to SO.

The real question is, will Solidarity support VS17, not the other way,

Could you provide details of any errors?

Comment: getting an error as shown in the above image

Comment: Right, there was no image showing, and I've typed out the error.

Comment: Can you tell me the step by step process how to solve the error?

Comment: If I knew that, Id have helped by now - I was just doing some tidying up of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consesys supports plugin for Visual studio. Download from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity)
It encounters problems for VS2017 which can be resolved as given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018949/the-install-of-solidity-extension-was-failed-for-visual-studio-2017)

I successfully installed plugin and I am able to see Solidity Smart contract projects in the project wizard. Still need to test it end to end.

Comment: The VS extension by Consesys still doesn't install correctly. This time the install error was 'Extension is signed with an invalid certificate'.